# How to avoid infinite loop with triggers between databases using postgres_fdw?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, replication

[schema of databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzu8X.jpg)

I want to synchronize 3 Postgresql databases across a central pivot db.

For example, if I insert a row in DB1, it sends a query to pivot db with the extension postgresql_fdw and it sends insert query to db2 and db3. I have created 3 triggers with `after insert` in each database.

The problem: if I insert in db1, the pivot send this query to db2 and db3 which fire their trigger to insert in db2 and db3 in return. Infinite loop :). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See [synchronizing two tables in postgres using DBlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31930985/1995738)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can check the nesting level with [**`pg_trigger_depth()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/different-replication-solutions.html).

Like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_sync_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() < 1)    -- cancel nested trigger invocation!
EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_sync_function();
```

- [How to prevent a PostgreSQL trigger from being fired by another trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103402/how-to-prevent-a-postgresql-trigger-from-being-fired-by-another-trigger/103661#103661)

**But** I have not tested this with `postgres_fdw` across databases. I doubt it works transparently across databases. You'll have to test ...

A poor man's solution would be to add a boolean flag `replicated` to each table, set it to true when the row is replicated, and only fire the replication trigger when it's not true.

```
...
WHEN (NEW.replicated = false)    -- cancel for replicated rows
...
```

But I can see all kinds of concurrency issues with this in a multi-user environment.

Have you considered one of the **proven replication solutions**? [Find a list in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/different-replication-solutions.html)